# Polynomial long division - intermediate steps missing

Tags: polynomials

I'm trying to find the intermediate step:
$$\frac{1}{(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{12}-\frac{x^4}{144}+...)^2} = \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{7}{12}+\frac{19x}{72} ...$$
Is there a quick way to find these first few terms that I'm missing here? Thanks

Comment: Do you want more terms or an explanation for the ones you know?

Comment: Using the assistance of a computer is the quickest way. However in order for readers to be able to critique your method (I assume long hand method) you have to give a little more information about the steps you have taken to obtain your displayed result.

Comment: Oh, sorry, so actually this was the solution provided us, going straight from the LHS to RHS, and I was hoping for an explanation as to how they came up with the first few terms on the RHS given those on the LHS. So an explanation for the ones I know would be most helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first terms of the doninator of the LHS are$$x^2-x^3+\frac{5 x^4}{12}-\frac{7 x^5}{72}+\cdots=x^2\left(1-x+\frac{5 x^2}{12}-\frac{7 x^3}{72}+\cdots\right).$$Therefore, the RHS can be written as$$\frac1{x^2}\left(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3+\cdots\right)$$and we must have$$\left(1-x+\frac{5 x^2}{12}-\frac{7 x^3}{72}+\cdots\right)\left(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3+\cdots\right)=1$$and therefore$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}b_0=1\\b_1-b_0=0\\b_2-b_1+\frac5{12}b_0=0\\b_3-b_2+\frac5{12}b_1-\frac7{72}b_0=0,\end{array}\right.$$from which we get that$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}b_0=1\\b_1=1\\b_2=\frac7{72}\\b_3=\frac{19}{72}.\end{array}\right.$$But that's all you can get from the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

There’s another way to do this by hand, but let me deal with a slightly more general situation. You may perform a division of power series in *exactly* the same way you learned to divide polynomials in high school, but by writing the terms in *ascending* order of degree instead of descending. If, for instance, you wanted 
$$
\frac1{x-x^2+2x^3-7x^4+\cdots}
$$
you would get the first monomial of the quotient to be $x^{-1}$, and write this up top; then multiply this by your denominator and subtract the result from $1$ to get $x-2x^2+7x^3+\cdots$; the next monomial of the quotient will thus be $1$, etc. I know that this is not much of an explanation—the process is best explained dynamically, at a blackboard.

In your particular case, I would expand the denominator, as $x^2-x^3+\frac5{12}x^4+\cdots$ and then divide this into $1$ by the method I sketched out above.